# Spring Security IP Address issues between Ethernet and WiFi

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ip-address

I am developing a Spring Boot Microservice using Spring Security.

As a part of the HTTP Security, I am using the "hasIpAddress" option:

```
http.csrf().disable();
http
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/**")
.hasIpAddress(env.getProperty("gateway.ip"))
.and()
.addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter());
```

As I am developing on my laptop, I am using a WiFi connection and my IP address is 192.168.1.15 for example. In the application properties, I set the IP address of the gateway to this which works fine.

When I am connected to the network by Ethernet cable, my IP address is 192.168.1.24. So, I would expect to use this IP address in the properties file. This does not work and debugging shows that it is trying to match against the loopback address of 127.0.0.1. Why?

Comment: When you are running locally, what URL are you using to access the endpoint?

Comment: Http://localhost:8012 which is the address of the gateway. I use that in both cases wi-fi and Ethernet.

Comment: Why don't you use the localhost address when working locally as obviously, both you backend service and gateway are living in the same box?

Comment: I don't have an issue with the connectivity I just want to know why when I have WiFi activated the hasIpAddress expects a 192... address and when I am using an ethernet cable (no WiFi) that it expects the loop back IP 127.0.0.1. sure everything is running locally .... The gateway gets the endpoint to use from an Eureka discovery service with which the endpoints register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what OS you're using but it could be that when you connect to ethernet, the configuration scripts are different than they are with wifi.

A simple test to see would be to connect to wifi only and from your terminal, ping localhost, and see what address resolves.  Then, do the same experiment with ethernet.

Localhost should always be 127.0.0.1, but it could be changed during the network configuration when you connect to wifi.

If you're on Mac or Linux, you can check the /etc/resolv.conf file after you connect to wifi.  In windows, I think you have to look at the DNS settings but I'm not sure, not a windows guy.